# Make nested route inside AuthenticatedRouteMixin accessible

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

I'd like to "free" one nested route, so that also users who are not even logged in can access this route.

**For example:**

`posts
- /create
- /edit
- /show`

On the `posts` route I used the `AuthenticatedRouteMixin`.
With this, all sub routes are automatically protected. Now I only want to make `/show` accessable. I know that I could use a mixin on `/create` and `/edit` and remove it from `posts` route, but if you have 10+ nested routes and only 1 of them should be available also for not logged in users, it's kind of inconvenient.

Do you know any other solution to that challenge?

If not, I think I have to write an additional mixin for that...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ember-simple-auth's AuthenticatedRouteMixin uses beforeModel hook to check whether session.isAuthenticated or not. You need to override the beforeModel in 'show' route to either skip the Auth check by bypassing AuthenticatedRouteMixin's super() implementation all together.

```
beforeModel (transition, skipAuthCheck) {
    if (!skipAuthCheck) {
       return this._super(...arguments, true);
    }
}
```

Check if the 'show' beforeModel has dependency with parent route .i.e 'posts', implement this check at the parent route.

Comment: I'll check it out in the following days.

Thanks for now!

Answer (score 0):

You could fake a nested route, by using the path parameter:

```
this.route('posts', function() {
    this.route('create');
    this.route('edit');
});
this.route('posts-show', { path: '/posts/show' });
```

Comment: I definitely want to avoid this because I want to keep my files semantically organized under `posts` folder.

Thanks for replying anyway!